# PHP not displaying PDF file in Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf

I wanted to display PDF files in browser using this code

```
<?php
    $file = './path/to/the.pdf';
    $filename = 'Custom file name for the.pdf'; /* Note: Always use .pdf at the end. */

    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    @readfile($file);
?>
```

The code works well in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I haven't tested in any other browser. Is it a bug with Chrome? Is there anyway I could make it so it is displayed in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Well, does chrome forcing your pdf to download? Also why do you use @ before readfile?

Comment: probably a header issue.

Comment: This code works for me. Have you try to update you chrome, or try it on some other comp? Maybe there is some add-on that could cause a problem?

Comment: Chrome does not forcing the pdf to download, just stuck at loading icon. Have no problem if using firefox.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. I noticed it happens only with PDF files bigger than 64K. The chrome console (Network) reports Status Code:206 Partial Content...

Answer (score 2):

Just change the content disposition to attachment

```
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```

This will not display the PDF in the browser, but in Chrome it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your browser setting and not on the code. Usually by default firefox will open the pdf in browser whereas it is not in the case of chrome

Comment: I have no problem opening the pdf in firefox with the same code, just with chrome. It just showing loading icon at bottom left but never open the pdf.

Comment: No it's not a browser setting... the code works with small PDFs (<64K)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem before, but not all computers had the issue. In my case I had some setting using Adobe or the default Chrome PDF reader. Check your settings.

Comment: which setting should I check?

Answer (score 0):

Is `$file` just the path to the file without the file name itself? Is that case you should use instead:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("$file/$filename"));
```